# How to convert Pytorch model parameters to long datatype?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I was able to convert pytorch model parameters to float or double but not to long.

```
model = model.long()
```

gives error, while

```
model = model.float()
```

runs.

The error I get is:

> ```
> 'Net' object has no attribute 'long'
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Most `nn` modules do not support long (integer) operations, e.g., convolutions, linear layer etc. Therefore, you cannot "cast" a model to `torch.long`.

Comment: How can I slove an error like an Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Double for argument #2 'mat2' where the obvious solution is to convert the dtype of the model.

Comment: @AnubhavNatani the obvious solution is to change the data type of the argument, rather than the model/parameters.

Comment: @AnubhavNatani I think you need to ask a *new* question with all the information on the specific error you encounter.

Comment: I had change the datatype of the data which I am giving to the model how can I change the data type of the argument mat2.